# Is the phrase "It is the only city FROM Latin America that I have visited" correct?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, prepositions

I don’t know if it is okay to use the word "from".

Comment: I think it would be more idiomatic to say " the only city in Latin America that I have visited"

Comment: More common to say " It is the only city *of* Latin America that I have visited". But I hope to see more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable question because there are many meanings of the word that may have led you to confusion {although as a newcomer you have omitted to refer to your research on the matter, and that is strongly encouraged in questions put on this site - please read the site tour}.

Among the meanings of *from* are:

> = *used to show the origin of something or someone*
>
> = *used to show the position of something in comparison with other things, or the point of view of someone when considering a matter or problem*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from)

Hence "*the only city originating in South America ...*" or "*the only city positioned in South America ...*" *that I have visited*.

I also suggest that the usage might be justified by its implied reference to selection from a set of cities, as in the following. My own explanatory note is shown {so}:

"*the only city* {taken from the set of cities of} *from South America ...*"